# Angular: CSS class usage within innerHtml of a cell

Tags: css, angular, innerhtml

I am fighting with this CSS issue, or angular, ...
The problem is that the CSS class used in a DIV element of my table cell is ignored.

I copied the basic example of https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples as this is what I want to use.

within the css file I added:

> .test-css {
>        color: orange;
>    }

then I modified the html template in order for one cell to call a method from my component class to get the innerHTML code:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [innerHtml]="getInnerHtml(element)"</td>
```

The method looks like that:

```
public getInnerHtml(element) {
    return `<div class="test-css">${element.name}</div>`;
}
```

The name is not displayed in orange.

If I apply the the test-css to the cell itself in the component template:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="test-css [innerHtml]="getInnerHtml(element)"</td>
```

then the column correctly appear in orange.

If I change on the component encapsulation to None, it works but the overall table layout is completely disturbed.
So I expect some issue in the way the innerHtml is interpreted.

Any idea if there is a way to solve it and to have the innerHtml correctly interpreted?

Thanks

Comment: If you apply ::ng-deep to your css, does that help?  Details [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: Thanks so much, it works!
The documentation seems to mention that it is deprecated, so I hope it will survive.

Comment: Yes, it is deprecated which is why I didn't suggest it as an answer (just as a comment).  However there isn't a good replacement that I know of, other than to change the encapsulation which as you found out has other effects.

Comment: Thanks again.

If anyone reading this has an option to replace the deprecated ::ng-deep I would be glad to try it.

Comment: I have the same problem, I don't think it's CSS related. It's looks like `[innerHTML]="..."` will not work on **MatCell**; it's only work as innerText

Answer (score -1):

in mat table inner html is not woking so insted of [innerHtml] use[innerText].